# How to add full customization into custom wordpress gutenberg block?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

i am writing my own custom wordpress block.
In editor it looks like this:
[edtor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MoYW.png)

And after it gets saved it looks like this:
[page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6RmV.jpg)

The problem is that i am using `RichText` wordpress component for text on the right side of the block, but i can't add some lists, buttons or other media inside it.
How to add this functionality to my custom block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [InnerBlocks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/) to create a container block for multiple different components. In your screenshot example, instead of using a RichText control, the [core/paragraph](https://wordpress.org/support/article/paragraph-block/) block has formatting controls and can also transform from a paragraph into a list if needed.

If your block design is of a 'fixed' layout where there will always be "text / list / button", you can define a template of which blocks are allowed in InnerBlocks and then lock the template so new blocks cannot be added, eg:

```
const MY_TEMPLATE = [
    ['core/paragraph'],
    ['core/list'],
    ['core/buttons'],
];

// ...
edit: () => {
    return (
        <InnerBlocks
            templateLock="all" // optional
            template={MY_TEMPLATE}
        />
    );
},
```

The example above would create a Block layout in the Editor like:
[image: WordPress Gutenberg Editor]

For a complete overview and example of how to implement InnerBlocks, refer to the WordPress Developer Docs:
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much!